# 'method' object has no attribute 'inner_html'

Tags: python, django

I have made a web site by seeing django tutorial. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/
I got an error
AttributeError at /polls/1/
'method' object has no attribute 'inner_html'  .
Traceback says

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  130.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/XXX/djangostudy/polls/views.py" in detail
  40.         form = VoteForm(question=obj)

File "/Users/XXX/djangostudy/polls/forms.py" in __init__
  21.         self.fields['choice'].widget.render.inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}<br>'

Exception Type: AttributeError at /polls/1/
Exception Value: 'method' object has no attribute 'inner_html'
```

My forms.py is like

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False,label='テキスト')

class VoteForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=None,
        label='選択',
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label=None,
        error_messages={
            'required':"You didn't select a choice.",
            'invalid_choice':"invalid choice.",
        },
    )

    def __init__(self,question,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'].queryset = question.choice_set.all()
        self.fields['choice'].widget.render.inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}<br>'
```

Setting of radio button is written in detail.html,like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'poll_vote' question.id %}" method="post">
<!--<form action="" method="post">-->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
    {% endfor %}
    <!--{{ form }}-->
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
</html>
```

views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from .models import Question
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,redirect
from .models import Choice
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import MyForm
from .forms import VoteForm


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'polls/index.html',{
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
    })

def detail(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VoteForm(question=obj,data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('polls:results',pk)
    else:
        form = VoteForm(question=obj)
    return render(request,'templates/polls/detail.html',{
        'form':form,
        'question': obj,
    })

def vote(request,pk):
    pass

def results(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'polls/results.html',{
        'question':obj,
    })

def form_test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #request.POST???
        form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request,'polls/form.html',{
        'form':form,
    })
```

I do not know how to fix it.I cannot understand why this error happen. WHat should I do to fix this?
The tutorial had `inner_html`,so I think it is necessary to do something needed.But,is it useless?

I wanna show the page like
[image]
in this part
    self.fields['choice'].widget.render.inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}
'

I wanna make this page is radio button page.

Comment: It's saying that `render` is a method (function), so presumably you need to call it first, like `render()`, although I'm not familiar with django so can't say how you're supposed to be using it

Comment: Why are you trying to set `widget.render.inner_html`? It isn't mentioned in the tutorial, or used anywhere in the Django codebase.

Comment: thx,ur comments.u means render(inner_html)?? It happens error.

Comment: @Alasdair Oh really??

Comment: @Alasdair polls/forms.py
class VoteForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'].queryset = question.choice_set.all()
        self.fields['choice'].widget.renderer.inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}<br>'

Comment: @Alasdair I saw this code.So,how can i fix this to achieve my goal?

Comment: In your comment you have `widget.renderer.inner_html`, but in your code you have `widget.render.inner_html`. Note that Django introduced [template-based widget rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#template-based-widget-rendering) in Django 1.11, so code written for earlier versions might not work in Django 1.11.

Comment: what goal are you trying to achieve? What are you expecting this line `self.fields['choice'].widget.render.inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}<br>'` to do?

Comment: @Alasdair Before, I got an error ,'RadioSelect' object has no attribute 'renderer'.So,i cannot write like  widget.renderer.So,do u think I cannot write the way of widget.render.inner_html ?

Comment: @dirkgroten I updated mu question.if u know something,please tell me.

Comment: `widget.render.inner_html` looks completely wrong. If you search for it, you don't get any results. Using `widget.renderer.inner_html` might have worked on earlier versions of Django, but won't work in Django 1.11.

Comment: If you want to have a radio button, then setting `widget=forms.RadioSelect,` is enough. You shouldn't have to alter the widget in the `__init__` method.

Comment: the problem is that `widget.renderer` doesn't have the attribute `inner_html` in Django 1.11 anymore. What happens if you just remove the line entirely? You already are using the RadioSelect widget, so it should just show up.